# How to hook text messages in iphone

Tags: iphone, sms

I'm trying to develope an iphone application which helps for filtering spam text messages.
But I don't know how to hook text messages.
Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just can't. iOS API as of today does not give you access to text messages. Not to read them, not to send them, not to filter them. Sorry to break you bad news.

If your phone is jailbroken, you could do it by accessing the SQLITE database where text messages are stored. But you definitely won't be able to distribute your application through AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you are trying to do, you are going to need to hook into the API. It is possible to jailbreak an iPhone without it being identified as 'jail-broken', though it's a bit tricky and a single screw up can deem your HID jailbroken for life.

If you're attempting to make a program usable for any user, this is not the method you want to use.

The only way this would be possible, is through a virus.